# Is Android Emulator packed with Android SDK or Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have an understanding problem with Android Emulators

Whether is it packed derived from Android Studio or Android SDK, Some posts mentioned the SDK offers emulators while other post describing it bundled with Android IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Android Emulator release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator)

> Android Emulator is included with Android Studio.
>
> Versions of the emulator prior to 25.3.0 were distributed as part of
> the Android SDK Tools.
>
> To ensure you have the latest version, check the SDK Manager for
> updates.
>
> For Android Emulator versions prior to 25.3.0, see the Android SDK
> Tools release notes.